# $n$-dimensional complex vectors form a connected set

Tags: general-topology

Consider the following set
$$X = \left\{x \in \mathbb{C}^n \; \vert \; \vert Re(x) \vert > \vert Im(x) \vert\right\}$$
where $n\geq 3$ and $Re(x)$ and $Im(x)$ are the real and imaginary parts of $x$ respectively. I want to know if this set is connected or not.

I have looked at the case where $n=1$ (I know $n\geq 3$ in the statement above but I wanted to do it as an exercise). For this, I think that the set is disconnected because if I define the two sets
$$Y = \left\{x \in X \; \vert \; Re(x) > 0\right\}$$
$$Z = \left\{x \in X \; \vert \; Re(x) < 0\right\}$$
then I have two disjoint open sets whose union is $X$ and therefore, $X$ must be disconnected.

1. Do people agree with my logic here for the case where $n=1$?
2. Also, does anyone have any suggestions on how I might approach the $n\geq 3$ case.

Comment: Your reasoning for (1) is fine, except that you need also to note that $Y$ and $Z$ are non-empty and, depending on the level of your course, you might need to justify why they are open.  However, @abx is [right](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/440531/n-dimensional-complex-vectors-form-a-connected-set#comment1136294_440531) about a better home for this question.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments, I will use MSE in the future for such questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}$Take any natural $n\ge2$. Then $X$ is connected.

Indeed, take any $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ and $y=(y_1,\dots,y_n)$ in $X$, so that $|a|>|b|$ and $|c|>|d|$, where $a:=\Re x:=(\Re x_1,\dots,\Re x_n)$, $b:=\Im x:=(\Im x_1,\dots,\Im x_n)$, $c:=\Re y$, and $d:=\Im y$.

We want to connect $x$ and $y$ in $X$ by a continuous curve. On the sphere $|a| S^{n-1}$ in $\mathbb R^n$ of radius $|a|$ centered at the origin, continuously connect $a$ to $a_c:=\frac{|a|}{|c|}\,c$. Similarly, on the sphere $|b|S^{n-1}$, continuously connect $b$ to $b_d:=\frac{|b|}{|d|}\,d$ (letting $b_d:=b$ if $d=0$). Since the movements from $a$ to $a_c$ and from $b$ to $b_d$ were on spheres centered at the origin, we have just continuously connected -- in $X$ -- the point $x=a+ib$ to the point $x_y:=a_c+ib_d$.

For $t\in[0,1]$, let now
$$z_t:=A_t+iB_t,\quad A_t:=(1-t)a_c+tc,\quad B_t:=(1-t)b_d+td.$$
Then $z_0=a_c+ib_d=x_y$, $z_1=c+id=y$, $|A_t|=(1-t)|a|+t|c|$, and $|B_t|=(1-t)|b|+t|d|$. Therefore and because $|a|>|b|$ and $|c|>|d|$, we have $|A_t|>|B_t|$ for all $t\in[0,1]$, so that $z_t\in X$ for all $t\in[0,1]$.

So, we have continuously connected in $X$ the point $x$ to the point $x_y$ to the point $y$.

This means that $X$ is [path-connected and hence connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space#Path_connectedness). $\quad\Box$

---

(The above proof fails to hold for $n=1$ because then the sphere $S^{n-1}=\{-1,1\}$ is not connected.)

Comment: Thanks so much for this! When I looked up the definition of connected set, it said that a set is connected if there doesn't exists two disjoin open sets, whose intersection is the null set and whose union is the set itself. This is what I had in mind when doing the proof above for $n=1$. You seemed to have shown here that any two points in $X$ can be continuously connected and therefore $X$ is connected. Is this definition equivalent to the one I was working with or am I not fully understanding your proof?

Comment: @jcb2535 : Every path-connected space is connected (the converse is not true in general). (This holds because the image of every path is connected, being a continuous image of an interval, which latter is connected). I have added a link to this statement.

Comment: Thanks very much, you've been very helpful!